# How to add jquery code inside php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I search Google and find lots of link for similar but none help me,,, how to add a piece of jquery code inside `<?php......?>`

here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(){$j('.number').Number();});</script>
```

Comment: can't use jquery code in php, it should be in script tag, why you want like that?

Comment: @AyyanarG if you are not sure, please don't misguide :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){$j('.number').Number();});</script>";
```

Just echo the jquery or javascript, you have to make sure that you don't break the string while echoing the javascript or jquery

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1):

@Danyal Sandeelo , thank you, the changes  you made didn't work but it gave me help so I change the code as bellow and it work fine.

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">var $j = jQuery.noConflict();$j(document).ready(function(){$j('.number').Number();});    </script>";
```

Comment: Always accept the right answer. Also you could post this info as a comment to answer, not creating new answer.